# Evaluate the truth of a statement

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

This is a question that appears in *A Concise Introduction To Pure Mathematics* by Martin Liebeck:

> Is the following statement true? $$n = 3 \text{ only if } n^2 - 2n - 3 = 0$$ (no domain for $n$ is specified)

My answer is that the statement is false, since there are also other relations that imply $n = 3$ such as $n - 3 = 0$, and also beacause the polynomial has more than one root, but in the official solutions it appears to be true. I think that my understanding of $only\ if$ is flawed, can someone explain what am I getting wrong?

Comment: But still **if $n=3$ then $n^2-2n-3=0$** is true, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, when written like that it's obviously true, the problem is with the "only if" translation. From what I understand, "only if" shows the necessity of a condition, not its sufficiency (that is "if"). From my point of view $n = 3$ is sufficient, but not necessary, since -1 is also a root.

Comment: I had trouble interpreting 'only if' in the past. I think of '$A$ only if $B$' as: $A$ true and $B$ false is impossible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'P only if Q' translates as $P \rightarrow Q$

Here is an illustrative example:

> 'You can be a bachelor only if you are male.' (True)

This of course does *not* mean that

> 'if you are male, then you are a bachelor' (False)

but it *does* mean that:

> 'if you are not male, then you cannot be a bachelor' (True)

which by *contraposition* is the same as:

> 'if you are a bachelor then you are male' (True)

So the statement you posted means:

> 'If $n=3$ then $n^2-2n-3=0$'

Which is True.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it makes sense!

Comment: @VladDinu You're welcome! :)